# Grab micro-controller info

Tags: c#, microcontroller, arduino

I have a client that is supposed to grab data from a micro-controller ( Arduino if you are familiar with it ), that transmits once a second a line of values, and send that data to a server to which the client is connected .

How should i do that ? The micro-controller when connected to the PC , 'shoots' data on one of the COMs.. should i approach the problem as a client-server ? I mean should i connect with my client to the micro-controller passing the mcontroller's port ? And if so, can anyone give me a link to such a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're writing You could just download a port-analyzer to check what's coming in.

```
http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/
```

You can also write a simple macro in excel that grab data and output to sheet,
just open the com-port with the right settings.

If it's an 24/7-application, I'd recommend a simple complied program running as a service, .NET or maby compiled script, autoit3 or similar (if you're on win32).

```
http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/19769-phone-dialer-using-com-to-modem-on-serial-port/
(3:rd post, Martin)
```

Regards,
//t